# How to sort object of objects by nested key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

i have an object of objects. i want to sort it on the basis of `id`.

here is my data

```
{
  1918: {
    id: "1544596802835",
    item_id: "1918",
    label: "Soft Touch  Salt Free Mint 500 ml (000001400045)",
    combo_items: false
  }

  6325: {
    id: "15445968134652",
    item_id: "6325",
    label: "Mirindas Orange Flover 300 ml (012000800160)",
    combo_items: false
  }

  6336: {
    id: "15445968106815",
    item_id: "6336",
    label: "Sting Energy 250ml (012000034220)",
    combo_items: false
  }

  6498: {
    id: "1544596806967",
    item_id: "6498",
    label: "Tido Candy (01)",
    combo_items: false
  }

  7461: {
    id: "15445968057103",
    item_id: "7461",
    label: "Skin Whitening Facial Kit (000051032012)",
    combo_items: false
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually that's an object literal, not JSON

Comment: @hindmost i know its object literal, how can i sort the data on the basis of 'id'

Comment: Show what you have tried first

Comment: Actually, that's an invalid object literal, not JSON.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen how can i sort this on the basis of 'id'

Comment: Objects cannot be sorted. Only arrays can.

Comment: an objects order cannot be garunteed, so how do you want this to be sorted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't rely on property order in JavaScript objects (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) for details), which means that you need to sort your objects into an array.

That can easily be done using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
const sorted = Object.values(data).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

---

Complete snippet:

```js
const data = {
  1918: {
    id: "1544596802835",
    item_id: "1918",
    label: "Soft Touch  Salt Free Mint 500 ml (000001400045)",
    combo_items: false
  },
  6325: {
    id: "15445968134652",
    item_id: "6325",
    label: "Mirindas Orange Flover 300 ml (012000800160)",
    combo_items: false
  },
  6336: {
    id: "15445968106815",
    item_id: "6336",
    label: "Sting Energy 250ml (012000034220)",
    combo_items: false
  },
  6498: {
    id: "1544596806967",
    item_id: "6498",
    label: "Tido Candy (01)",
    combo_items: false
  },
  7461: {
    id: "15445968057103",
    item_id: "7461",
    label: "Skin Whitening Facial Kit (000051032012)",
    combo_items: false
  }
};

const sorted = Object.values(data).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(sorted);
```

<sup>(I fixed the object literal as it was lacking commas between the properties)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

*You can try!*

```
function sort(data) 
{
   return Object.keys(data)
   .sort().reduce((a, b) => {
   a[b] = data[b];
   return a; }, {});
}

const object = {9:"Name 9", 10:"Name 10", 2:"Name 2", 5:"Name 5", 3:"Name 3"};
var sortObject = sort(abject);
```

*The result is*

```
sortObject = {2: "Name 2", 3: "Name 3", 5: "Name 5", 9: "Name 9", 10: "Name 10"}
```